# Fortran function to start reading from specific line of input file?

Tags: io, fortran

I am working with a very large input file but the information I need only starts halfway through the file. Is there a way to start reading the input file at a certain line?

I am currently reading each line from the start of the file just to skip it but this can take quite a while depending on the size of the input file.

```
implicit none
integer :: i

open(99, file = 'input.dat')

do i=1, 10000
  read(99,*)
end do            ! skips the first 10,000 lines of file input.dat
```

This works but when I want to skip say 95,038,000 lines it takes a considerable amount of time and since I know what line I want to start reading from is there a way to start from that line?

My input file looks like this (... indicating much of the same):

```
100
1      0.01    20000    20000
He            51.71286      -72.51866      -18.82236
He            26.74500      -55.83966      -21.50548
He            54.21926       10.26991       55.95801
      ...
He            53.88083       36.44334      -12.26679
He           -73.74439      -15.63201      -73.70352
He           -64.81084      -24.94384      -76.42190
100
2      0.01    20000    20000
He           -75.32897      -18.60672       25.41119
He           -26.30221      -58.53324      -61.39479
He           -64.44293      -28.82557      -15.57422
      ...
```

Comment: You can probably do what you want by (a) calculating the file position at which you want to start reading - measured in bytes most likely; and (b) opening the file for `stream` access at that position.  Edit your question to ask about implementing this approach if you need to. BUT the i/o system may well read through the file to get to that position, so I'm not sure it will be worth your time.  I presume you have no power to go back and write the data into a more direct-access store, eg HDF5 files or a database or ...